# Prevent Specific JS Loaded by iframe from Running on my Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, adsense

I want to know if it is possible to block JS, loaded by an iframe, from running on my Wordpress site. I currently embed iframe generated by a service I pay to use for my business. The iframe comes with Google AdSense ads embedded in it. Recently, the rogue pop-ups have been affecting my customers. Essentially, these are ads that run on the mobile version of my site and initiate a series of redirects. I can prevent these on my own device with an AdBlocker, but not all of my customers are that savvy.

I have tried to disable the Google AdSense ads a few ways: CSS display:none; (fails, as the JS is loaded even if the element is hidden with CSS), PHP (created a plugin that leverages wp_deqeue_script, targeting the google ad script files (blocks some JS, but ultimately fails to prevent every instance of the ads), and even HTML in the head section of my site,  (the idea is that it prevents loading sources outside my domain, fails).

Is there a way to programmatically prevent these JS files from loading on my site?

Comment: Only way is not to embed it in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not so much you can do about it. As @charietfl states in the comment you should think in the first place about not embedding this at all if that is a possibility for you.

From programming perspective there is only one reliable thing you can do: use iframe sandbox mode.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

This way you can prevent the IFRAME target from running ANY scripts - I do not know though if its a valid scenario for you. Otherwise there is actually no reliable way to affect the loaded iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to achieve the results I was looking for, while retaining the functions of the iframe, using the following: sandbox="allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock". This allowed the necessary scripts of the iframe to run on my site, but prevented the popup-generating ad scripts.